# Часто встречающиеся символы

Tags: c, символы, ascii

Задача состоит в том, чтобы в начале строки стояли более часто встречающиеся символы. Сначала я решил записать ascii кода символов в массив от 0 до 255, то есть индекс элемента это ascii код а значение элемента - то количество раз, которое он встречается в строке. А дальше моя мысль застопорилась. Как теперь можно перенести символы в строку, чтобы она была отсортирована по частоте символов.

```
int main(){
    char str[]="asdffffaaahh";
    int len=strlen(str);
    char rez[len];
    int idx[256]={0}, k;
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
        k=str[i];
        idx[k]+=1;
    }
//puts(rez);
}
```

Comment: Ну вы добавьте в структуру данных код символа, и отсортируйте по количеству вхождений. Дальше очевидно.

Comment: @VladD Можно подробнее про сортировку по количеству вхождений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо массива `int idx[256]` заводите структуру

```
struct char_and_quantity
{
    char c;
    int quantity;
};
```

Заводите массив `struct char_and_quantity idx[256];` Заполняете поле `c`символами от 0 до 255, затем, пробегаясь по строке, подсчитываете количество.

Сортируете вашу структуру по полю `quantity`, используя `qsort`, по убыванию. После этого на первом месте в массиве будет самый частый символ, и количество раз, которое он встречается, на втором — второй по частоте и т. д.

Дальше уже легко собрать снова вашу строку.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59292/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd---).